# Positive value for a symbol in Maple

Tags: maple

I need to describe variable as positive. 
It used as a parameter in a piece-wise function, and it is positive by definition, but I don't know how to set it as unknown positive. I need something like unsigned in c++, but for Maple.
Any advices?

**Upd:**

For example:
I made some evaluation and got this as the result:

```
  piecewise(h <= 0, 0, 0 < h, (1/3)*h)  (1)
```

but by some reasons h > 0, so I want to simplify (1). How do I set this into Maple?

Comment: Something other than [`unsigned int`](http://leaflabs.com/docs/lang/cpp/unsignedint.html)?

Comment: There are 2 problems with it
1) I am not sure how to set variable as unsigned in Maple, I searched in Maple help for it, no luck.
2) Unsigned is non-negative and I need positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To indicate to Maple the value is positive real, use

```
assume(h>0);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not really clear what you want, since you've described the issue in loose terms. What do you mean, in a technical Maple sense, by "describe" here? And "function"?

```
f:=proc(x::positive) if x>1 then y else z end if end proc:

f(4);
                           y

f(-4);
Error, invalid input: f expects its 1st argument, x, to be of type positive,
but received -4
```

In light of the update to the post: perhaps you want something like this,

```
f:=piecewise(h <= 0, 0, 0 < h, (1/3)*h):

simplify(f) assuming h>0;

                          1  
                          - h
                          3
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, in my case assume(h>0) was a little bit better.